# Graph Data Structure Within JSON

Tags: javascript, graph, tree

How would I go about creating a graph like data structure in javascript? I want to have a link within the structure that points some where else within the structure.

Like in this example:

```
var MenuLayout = {
    home: {
        buttons: [{
            text: "Identify Tree",
            link: MenuLayout.treeid
        }, {
            text: "Plant"
        }, {
            text: "Information"
        }, {
            text: "Enter Tree"
        }]
    },
    treeid: {
        buttons: [{
            text: "Something Else"
        }]
    }
};
```

In this example I would like `MenuLayout.home.buttons[0].link` point to `MenuLayout.treeid` node. Is there a way to get it to point to that?

NOTE: I want this to work for an arbitrary order of declaration.

Comment: Lots of suggestions in that other questions. Everything is a workaround though, since it's not possible to do what you want to do.

Comment: You should probably create separate classes for graph and nodes. This would solve the object-literal self reference issue.